# In Jekyll is there an easy way to change an output path for a folder with html

Tags: jekyll, liquid, jekyll-extensions

I am using Jekyll for some static site templates and I have a folder of product html pages which I want to be bundled into the root **site/** folder rather than into a **site/products** folder.

example below with just 2 product pages:

***src folder***

- src/products/123.html
- src/products/146.html

***output to site***

- site/123.html
- site/146.html

Is there an easy way to do this?

Additionally would there be an easy way to append **products-** to each file in this folder?

- site/product-123.html
- site/product-146.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking into Jekyll [collections](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/). You'll specifically want the [Permalink feature](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/). Hopefully the following snippet will get you started.

***config.yml***

```
collections:
  products:
    output: true
    permalink: /product-:title/
```

***source tree***

```
_products
    |
    1.html
    2.html
    3.html
    ...
```

***output tree***

```
_site
    |
    product-1
        |
        index.html
    product-2
        |
        index.html
    product-3
        |
        index.html
    ...
```

This creates the "pretty permalinks" structure where file endings are removed by using `index.html` within a directory of the correct name. Of course you could set it to create the "ugly permalinks" (`project-1.html`, etc), but I like this style more.

Comment: cool thanks, I have actually been using collections for this, and it works well

Comment: Im assuming thats supposed to be `_products` in the source tree?

Comment: Looks like it. I copied from my own website, which contains projects instead of products, so it's probably a typo. Fixed.